# here-document with bash -c

Tags: bash, ubuntu-22.04

This example script:

```
cat <<- EOF | bash -c
    command1 args
    command2 args
    command3 args
    command4 args
    command5 args
EOF
```

Returns: `bash: -c: option requires an argument`
How do I use bash -c with here-document?

Comment: Don't. You don't need `-c` here. Use `bash -s` instead.

Comment: To be a little more clear: `bash -c`'s whole point is to take a script off the argv. A heredoc isn't putting content on the argv, it's putting it on stdin; that's what `bash -s` is for. The only good reason I can think of to prefer `bash -c` over `bash -s` is to keep stdin available for other uses, and when you use a heredoc you defeat that point.

Comment: I don't need this standard input for other uses and only by removing the `-c` option, even without adding `-s`, it works.
If `bash -c` runs a list of commands and exits, how is it that even without that option it still exits if I use standard input?
If I use `bash` without stdin, it opens a new instance in the same terminal without exiting.

The thing that matters most to me is that `stdin | bash` and `bash -c argv` are functionally equivalent, i.e. have the same effect and result. Is it so?

Comment: "How is it even without that option it still exits" -- how could it _not_ exit? When it's reached the end of its stdin, _there are no more commands for it to run_, and nowhere it can read more of them from (because the file descriptor, on stdin, it was given to read commands from is closed). No action other than treating it as end-of-script makes sense in that case.

Comment: When you just run bash without any redirection, its stdin is connected to a terminal. When you close the terminal window, that's given to the shell as its stdin being closed, just like an end-of-file situation, and the shell exits. Which is to say, it's completely normal/typical/expected for an EOF on stdin to cause a shell reading commands from stdin to trigger an exit _even when that shell is interactive_, so there's no reason for you to anticipate behavior to be anything different when stdin is a non-terminal source.

Comment: this comment is perfect! A thousand thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to combine here-docuemnt with bash -c, try this :

```
bash -c "$(cat <<- EOF
    command1 args
    command2 args
    command3 args
    command4 args
    command5 args
EOF
)"
```

Comment: There's no need for `cat` or a here document at all; the argument to `-c` can contain embedded newlines.

Comment: Or just semicolons: `bash -c 'command1 args; cmmand2 args; ...; command5 args'`.

Comment: @chepner What if `args` contain single&double quotes ?

Comment: You can always enclose the argument in double quotes (or `$'...'`) and escape the contents as necessary.

Comment: That can become unreadable.

Comment: Thanks for the answer following the `argv` method but I found that the `stdin` method is more convenient in this case.

Comment: I take back what I said. Your method is superlative, I needed some input from outside.